# If object value is unique in array, do this

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, unique, javascript-objects

If i have an array of objects

```
[
    {name: 'John', count: 5, isunique: false, occupation: 'carpenter'}, 
    {name: 'Bob', count: 6,  isunique: false, occupation: 'carpenter'}, 
    {name: "John", count: 9, isunique: false, occupation: "barber"}
]
```

(this array is large), and I want to determine which occupations are unique, and on that condition return a new array where only the boolean isunique is changed like so:

```
[
    {name: 'John', count: 5, isunique: false, occupation: 'carpenter'}, 
    {name: 'Bob', count: 6,  isunique: false, occupation: 'carpenter'}, 
    {name: "John", count: 9, isunique: true, occupation: "barber"}
]
```

is this possible to do efficiently in Javascript with a large array?  I am completely at a loss here.

Comment: @adeneo I am only checking for uniqueness of the `occupation:` key-value pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```
var count = data.reduce(function(ret, el) {
    ret[el.occupation] = (ret[el.occupation] || 0) + 1;
    return ret;
}, {});

data.forEach(function(el) { el.isunique = count[el.occupation] === 1; });
```

Comment: This should be more optimal approach since it only needs to iterate over the data twice (as opposed to one iteration per item in worst case in @adeneo's answer).

Comment: thanks @vohuman, both answers worked, but since this one performs better I will make it the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the array and change the `isunique` property based on wether or not any of the other objects have the same occupation, like this

```
arr.forEach(function(item) {
    item.isunique = !arr.some(function(item2) {
        return item !== item2 && item.occupation === item2.occupation;
    });
});
```

```js
var arr = [
    {name: 'John', count: 5, isunique: false, occupation: 'carpenter'}, 
    {name: 'Bob', count: 6,  isunique: false, occupation: 'carpenter'}, 
    {name: "John", count: 9, isunique: false, occupation: "barber"}
]

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    item.isunique = !arr.some(function(item2) {
     return item !== item2 && item.occupation === item2.occupation;
    });
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4) + '</pre>'
```

Comment: thanks @adeneo! `array.prototype.some` is a useful method I never think to use!